# Clone a custom UserControl C# WPF - Easiest Way (Shallow Copy)

Tags: c#, wpf, clone

I want to Clone (Shallow Clone) a custom UserControl like:

```
ucButton uc;
ucButton uc2;
uc = uc2;
```

When I do this the compiler wants me to remove the old instance (uc) from canvas.

using:

```
Canvas1.Children.Add(uc)

Canvas2.Children.Add(uc2)
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't think that there is an easy way to achieve that: If your user control contains other reference type, should they be made common, or should they be copied too?

Moreover, you won't be able to get a complete list of the attached dependency properties on the UserControl.

Personnaly, I would encapsulate my user control in a DataTemplate in my xaml resources and create new instances of the usercontrol from the [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) as required.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ucButton">
  <myControls:ucButton ... />
</DataTemplate>
```

In your code, get the Template from the resources, then [load the content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/system.windows.frameworktemplate.loadcontent.aspx).

```
var uc = template.LoadContent() as UserControl;
var uc2 = template.LoadContent() as UserControl;
```

I understand it's not exactly what you are trying to do. My solution won't work if instantiating from xaml is not an option.

Comment: In fact, I propose you to instantiate from code behind, but declare from XAML. It won't work if you are changing somes properties of the control in code behind. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want to have one Usercontrol thats include database information from Dataset, I want to clone the Usercontrol object that includes information from the Dataset to a new usercontrol object.

Comment: Putting a DataSet in a UserControl looks like a bad idea to me. Couldn't you manage it in your domain layer instead of the view layer?

Comment: Sorry if I am missleading you, I have a Domain Layer, I am handling Dataset from another Class.

Comment: Couldn't you simply give to your second button the same Dataset reference when you instantiate it?